# Unable to fetch nodes from xml even with namespace management in place in java

Tags: java, xml, xmlnodelist

Below is the screenshot of the xml file i am working with, i need to get the value 'switchboardid1' from tag Extensions: 
[image: XML snippet]

Below is the code i have writen: I need to access property 'switchboardid1' from extensions tag. I always get only null in return. Please correct my code and help me understand.

I have NamespaceContext class to return the namespace in class 'HardcodedNamespaceResolver' and it is correctly returning the value of nfh namespace.

```
 public void test() throws Throwable
  {

 String xpath="//ElectricalProject/Equipments/Equipment/Extensions/Extension/nfh:extensionProperty[@name='switchboardId']";
Node node = GetNodeFromXml("PutNFInProj.xml",xpath);

Element ele = (Element) node;
System.out.println(ele.getNodeValue().toString());
   }

//Function to GET a single Node from xml file wrt to xpath defined
 public Node GetNodeFromXml(String XmlFileName, String xPathExpression) throws Throwable 
 {
     DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = builder.parse(GetDataFile(XmlFileName));
     ((org.w3c.dom.Document) doc).getDocumentElement().normalize();



     XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
     xPath.setNamespaceContext(new HardcodedNamespaceResolver());
     NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(xPathExpression,doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);


     switch (nodeList.getLength()) 
     {
        case 0:
            {
                log.error("In Function: GetNodeFromXml - There are no nodes with respect to given xpath, Please Check the Xpath");
                return null;
            }
        case 1:
            {
                Node nNode = nodeList.item(0);
                return nNode;   
            }

        default:
            {
                log.error("In Function: GetNodeFromXml- There are more than one nodes with respect to given xpath");
                return null;
            }
    }


 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXml can do it:

```
final String yourxml = ...
final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
System.out.println(getSwitchBoardId(simple.fromXml(yourxml)));

private static String getSwitchBoardId(final Element element) {
    return element.children.get(2).children.get(0).children.get(4).children.get(0).children.get(0).text;
}
```

Will output:

```
switchboardid1
```

From maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```